# Site content not showing

Tags: content

The guy I made a webpage somewhile ago, reported, that the site content was missing.
Checking it, I discovered, that there is no entry content displayed, not on any page, but the footers, headers, the base structure of the page still works.

After a quick search, I found it, that I should be turning off all plugins, and then I should be able to see the site contents. However, this was not the case, since turning off all plugins still did nothing.

If anyone has run across the likes, please provide me with some directions.

Otherwise, if you ask for certain parts of code or settings, I am happy to share them with you - I quitted working with wordpress some time ago, so please be easy on me.

Thanks in advance! :)

EDIT:

I have tried changing my theme, also checked the plugins one more time, but they are not the solution sadly.

However, looking at and meddling a bit with the code, I found, that the function "the_content()" doesn't load the content for any of the pages, instead it always loads the following:

```
<div style="position:absolute; left:-5879px;top:-1763px;">
  <a href="http://openup-h2020.eu/index.php?wimlbk=best-ethereum-miner-linux">
  http://openup-h2020.eu/index.php?wimlbk=best-ethereum-miner-linux</a>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute;left:-2309px;top:-3751px;">
  <a href="http://www.lsc.de/index.php?hznbmo=slot-nuts-casino-bonus-code">
  in deutschland zugelassene online casinos</a>
  " seriöse online casinos novoline
  "
  <a href="http://www.lsc.de/index.php?hznbmo=besten-online-casinos">www.lsc.de</a>
</div>
```

So I wonder, could some have tempered with the wordpress code maybe?

Awaiting your answers and ideas.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that someone (something) deleted all of the entries in the wp-posts table. If you are comfortable working with phpMyAdmin, you could take a peek there.

It's also possible that your current theme might be 'borked' for some reason. So the advice on changing to one of the 'twenty' themes is a good idea.  And a plugin *might* cause problems with accessing the wp-post data.

I'd try first changing to a 'twenty' theme. Then disabling all plugins (especially those that you have added lately).

If you are still having problems, then it's possible that your site was hacked. I'd look at the generated page source to see if there is anything that shouldn't be there.

I'd also change/reset all access to the site: WP users, FTP users, Hosting account users, etc. A fresh install of WP, along with a fresh install of your current theme, might also be a good idea.